# Background view controller responding to touch events?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a main view controller which overrides 
`touchesBegan` and plays a sound when hitting a certain screen position. I have a show segue from this view controller to another one, my custom settings view controller. However, when I slide my finger across this new one, the background view controller is still responding to my touches, as a sound is still being played.

I do not have a navigation controller implemented, and it seems like other segue types have this same issue with the touch events responding in the background. Shouldn't the first view controller not be responding to these touches after the segue? Or if I am misunderstanding, what is the proper way to stop touch events being called in the background VC?

**Edit:** in first view controller, when printing `view.isUserInteractionEnabled`, I get `true` despite the view controller being in the background. Not sure if this is relevant.

**Edit 2:** I tried adding a line in prepare for segue override `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled=false`, but weirdly enough, only does this disable touch when dismissing the settings view controller.

Even more strange: if I override `touchesBegan` in my new view controller, it silences both the `touchesMoved` and `touchesBegan` methods in my original view controller. But if I just override `touchesMoved` in my new controller, the `touchesMoved` method in both view controllers are called.

I read that we need to override all 4 of the touch handlers and call the superclass method, which I forgot to do. But overriding all 4 methods in both these classes still cause this underlying touch event to go through.

I also would like to stick to this approach rather than a gesture recognizer. I'm assuming there has to be a proper way to handle what looks like this responder chain?

Here's a simple way to replicate: If you create a simple project with two view controllers, A and B, and have a button cause segue from A to B, and implement the touches method in VC A (and let's say print something to the console), then even after segue, the exact same thing happens. VC A is still handling touch events.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent touches on the previous view try presenting the next view to fullscreen.

```
let controller = segue.destination as! YourViewController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```